# In Java playing back audio using a clip isn't working with no error messages

Tags: java, audio, playback, clip

I've been trying to use the "Trail: Sound" from Oracle and I've gotten to this part. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html#113609
"Using a Clip"

Well I tried to follow the directions which aren't exactly specific and I made some code that seems like it should work. It basically matches examples I found online that work for other people. On my machine nothing happens the program ends without playing any sound right after I start it. It doesn't say any errors.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
class Demo{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException{
    File file = new File("song1.wav");
    AudioFileFormat audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
    AudioFormat audioFormat = audioFileFormat.getFormat();
    javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info(Clip.class,audioFormat);
    Line theLine = AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
    Clip clip = (Clip)theLine;
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start();
  }
}
```

EDIT: I figured out after clip.start() I needed to keep the program open.

Answer (score 0):

I use that class to play MP# sounds and works for me

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
import monitorbixao.Main;

/**
 *
 * @author C007329
 */
public class MusicPlayer extends Thread {

    private File music;
    private Player player;

    public MusicPlayer(File music) {
        this.music = music;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        play();
    }

    public void play() {
        try {
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(music);
            BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
            this.player = new Player(buffer);
            //System.out.println("Executando...");
            this.player.play();
            //System.out.println("Terminado");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println("Erro!");
            Main.logApp.addMsgLog(MusicPlayer.class.getCanonicalName(), e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        this.player.close();
        //System.out.println("Interrompido...");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the clip class like in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to keep the program open so after "clip.start();" I added this code

```
java.io.Console c = System.console();
    if (c == null) {
        System.err.println("No console.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
String nothing = c.readLine("Wait... ");
```

:D